# Creating folders and sub-folders with a VBA macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm looking to use a spreadsheet I've created to generate folders and sub-folders based on what is in each column.

The first column is the top level, the second column the next level down (sub-folder) and so on.

```
    A                 B                   C                   D
1   TOP FOLDER 1      Sub Folder 1.1      Sub Folder 1.2      Sub Folder 1.3
2   TOP FOLDER 2      Sub Folder 2.1      Sub Folder 2.2      Sub Folder 2.3
3   TOP FOLDER 3      Sub Folder 3.1      Sub Folder 3.2      Sub Folder 3.3
```

I've tried another program already and it made the folders but put them all in one folder! I need it with sub-folders, but I think an issue might be separating the folders, here's an example:

I'm thinking it may be problematic to separate the sub-folders into their parent folders because they are in the same columns...

Answer (score 5):

This creates a folder structure with VBA. Short and beautiful.

```
Sub CreateFolderStructure()
    Dim objRow as Range, objCell as Range, strFolders as String

    For Each objRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        strFolders = "C:\myRootFolder"            
        For Each objCell In objRow.Cells
            strFolders = strFolders & "\" & objCell
        Next            
        Shell ("cmd /c md " & Chr(34) & strFolders & Chr(34))
    Next    
End Sub
```

<sup>No error handling!</sup>

#### What it does

1. Loop through every used row of your active Excel sheet
2. Set the root folder in which our new folders should be created. Must be done in every loop
3. Loop through every used cell in the current row
4. Concatenate the root folder with a backslash and the new sub folder.
   Do this for every sub folder in that row until we get something like
   `"C:\myRootFolder\TOP FOLDER 1\SUB FOLDER 1.1\SUB FOLDER 1.2\SUB FOLDER 1.3"`
5. Now comes the magic. We do **not** use VBA's `mkdir` function.
   Instead we use [`Shell(cmd /c md)`](http://ss64.com/nt/md.html) which can make several folders with one command. It also produces no error if a folder already exists. Such a beautiful command

#### Some notes

- Avoid these characters in folder names: `© ® " - & ' ^ ( ) @`
- Empty Excel cells are no problem. The MD command can handle strings like `C:\root\\subfolder` with two consecutive backslashes
- Spaces in folder names are no problem since we wrap the complete structure with two quotation marks (`chr(34)`)

Comment: This code returns a Runtime error 424. It is fixed at http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/926017-creating-multiple-child-folders-under-parent-folder-using-visual-basic-applications.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub MkDirs()

    Const RootPath = "C:\your\path"
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Selection

    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        ChDir RootPath
        For Each cl In rw.Cells
            If cl <> "" Then
                MkDir cl
                ChDir cl
            End If
        Next
    Next 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better answer that allows you to choose a root file instead of defining it in the code:

```
Sub FolderCreator()

    Dim objRow As Range, objCell As Range, strFolders As String, rootFolder As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        ' show the file picker dialog box
        If .Show <> 0 Then
            rootFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
              End If
    End With

    For Each objRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        strFolders = rootFolder
        For Each objCell In objRow.Cells
            strFolders = strFolders & "\" & objCell
        Next
        Shell ("cmd /c md " & Chr(34) & strFolders & Chr(34))
    Next

End Sub
```