# Creation of a Folder Structure with a path defined in a cell (or pop-up)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm a new to using excel's VBA and was wondering if you could help me figure out a solution.

So I'm seeking to create an excel spreadsheet that will create a folder structure in a certain location.

The creation of a folder structure bit I solved by using the code from the following:

[Creating folders and sub-folders with a VBA macro](https://superuser.com/questions/799666/creating-folders-and-sub-folders-with-a-vba-macro)

The problem I have is defining the location from a cell,
I've attempted to use the following to define the path:

```
Dim strFolders As String
strFolders = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, "A").Value
```

which forms this code together

```
Sub CreateFolderStructure()
    Dim objRow As Range, objCell As Range, strFolders As String

    For Each objRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        Dim strFolders As String
            strFolders = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, "A").Value
        For Each objCell In objRow.Cells
            strFolders = strFolders & "\" & objCell
        Next
        Shell ("cmd /c md " & Chr(34) & strFolders & Chr(34))
    Next
End Sub
```

Unfortunately it isn't simple as that. I get a duplicate declaration error, though I don't understand where (nor why, so feel free to explain this to me).

Naturally, I expect that inserting the path into a cell will also create that as a folder (or an error due to '/'), so I'm also looking for a solution for that too (but I'm focusing on the problem in front of me right now), I was thinking of maybe creating a pop-up menu where you could define them, I'm not exactly sure how difficult that is but I'm still learning the ropes right now so my focus is on something easy for now.

I'm leaving this question open here in the meantime while I continue to figure out a solution myself, if I find an answer I will be sure to update this!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Since you have declared `strFolders` twice, once with others variables in `2nd Row` and second one in `Row 4`, so that you are getting `Duplicate declaration error`**

*Delete this row from the code you find in Row 4.*

```
 Dim strFolders As String
```

Comment: #Mateusz, glad to help you,, keep asking ☺