# Macro to create folder\subfolder\file.xlsm via Shell(cmd /c md)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, save-as

I found this amazing code by nixda ... which creates a folder\subfolder structure named with values from a worksheet's cells.

[Creating folders and sub-folders with a VBA macro](https://superuser.com/questions/799666/creating-folders-and-sub-folders-with-a-vba-macro/799970#799970) .

Would it be possible to add a file,  too (.xlsm)?

folder\subfolder\file.xlsm

The file name would be:

- today's date
- or anything else (via a cell)

Thank you!

Bee

Hello Hannu, thank you for replying.

This is the code:

Sub CreateFolderStructure()
' [Creating folders and sub-folders with a VBA macro](https://superuser.com/questions/799666/creating-folders-and-sub-folders-with-a-vba-macro/799970#799970)

```
Dim objRow As Range, objCell As Range, strFolders As String

For Each objRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
    strFolders = "C:\myRootFolder"
    For Each objCell In objRow.Cells
        strFolders = strFolders & "\" & objCell
    Next
    Shell ("cmd /c md " & Chr(34) & strFolders & ".xlsm" Chr(34))
Next
```

End Sub

It produces a commpile error: "Expected: list separator or )"

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Answer: yes.
How: Add the .xls name just before the `CHR$(34)` at the end.

Comment: Hi Hannu, thank you. It does not work the way I did it (compile error "invalid or unqualified reference").                                                                                                        
   Sub CreateFolderStructureSave()
    Dim objRow As Range, objCell As Range, strFolders As String

    For Each objRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        strFolders = "C:\"
        For Each objCell In objRow.Cells
            strFolders = strFolders & "\" & objCell
        Next
        Shell ("cmd /c md " & Chr(34) & strFolders & .xlsm & Chr(34))
    Next
End Sub

Comment: Please add the code to your question (mark it as code, use the toolbar), telling what result you got.